# How to copy the p4 changes in workspace to another?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have two workspaces A and B. I made some changes in A and the code is not committed to p4. I want to copy the modified files to workspace B.

What is the easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `p4 shelve` in workspace A to store the files on the server without submitting them.

Then use `p4 unshelve` in workspace B to get the modified files.